# Regex fix malformed JSON

Tags: python, regex

So basically I got this malformed JSON:

```
'status': {'$content': 'Completed'}
```

`'status': 'Completed'` <-- expected

```
'foobar': {'$content': 1}
```

`'foobar': 1` <-- expected

I tried `(([^{'\$content':]))` to not match the `{'$content':` since this will always be useless.

However I have no idea how to get the second Group to actually *match* the correct value, and strip off the last `}`.

```
"SkillTreeModel":{"idToLevelDict2.0":{"TapDmg":2,"TapDmgFromHelpers":1,"PetDmg":0,"PetGoldQTE":13,"HeavyStrikes":16,"FireTapSkillBoost":0,"PetQTE":0,"Frenzy":0,"BossDmgQTE":0,"AllHelperDmg":15,"ChestGold":1,"HelperDmgSkillBoost":16,"ClanShipDmg":15,"HelperBoost":14,"HelperInspiredWeaken":1,"ClanQTE":16,"HelperDmgQTE":12,"ClanShipStun":0,"MPCapacityBoost":0,"MidasSkillBoost":0,"BurstSkillBoost":0,"CloneDmg":0,"Fairy":0,"ManaStealSkillBoost":0,"CloneSkillBoost":0,"ManaMonster":0,"CritSkillBoost":0,"BossTimer":0,"OfflineGold":11,"MultiMonsters":1,"CritSkillBoostDmg":3,"UltraDagger":1,"StrokeOfLuck":6,"SoulBlade":0,"Cloaking":1,"ForbiddenContract":0,"PoisonedBlade":0,"GuidedBlade":13,"None":0},"firstTimeSeeNewSkillTree":{"$content":true},"hasResetTreeThisPrestige":{"$content":false}}
```

If there is a pythonic way I'd be thankful too.

Comment: Can't you just modify the dictionary once you've got it in Python?

Comment: I've checked but I couldn't find a way to do so. Regex'ing this away is like my last hope right now. If you got another pythonic idea go on :)

Comment: Perhaps your question should be about how to modify the dictionary…

Comment: You've chosen the deep dark long road. good luck. I believe that's is a string output which is supposed to be `JSON` dict. you've to browse the community and check how to load into `JSON`, then you can delete the key which you don't need

Comment: This is some pseudo-string I don't understand. Can you show us a modest bit of python or a real JSON string? How is this not `foo['status'] = foo['status']['$content']`?

Comment: @tdelaney he's dealing with `JSONP` string which is need to be dumped and loaded into `JSON` firstly in order to be accessed, have you noticed `true/false` ?

Comment: @tdelaney thats exactly the point. I want to access the valiue by `foo['status']`, some are accessible like that and some have this `$content` key

Comment: @0x45 - That's what I'm getting at. It seems like you've posted a fragment of a JSON stream. if its a valid JSON string that can be loaded into python, then the substitution is what I've shown. If this is part of, say, a <script> that has been read but can't just be loaded with `json.loads()`, that's a different problem. You don't have enough context to know what to do.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη - we don't know what these examples are. JSONP, for instance, has never been mentioned. If so, this is part of a <script> element and he should tell us that.  If OP can write them either as a python string (assuming these have not been deserialized to python) or a python object, then we can work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `object_hook` to [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) to check for the dictionary containing the `$content` key and replacing it with the value. Note that your `JSON` is missing containing `{}` so you need to add them:

```
import json

def is_content(dct):
    if '$content' in dct:
        return dct['$content']
    return dct

d = json.loads('{"SkillTreeModel":{"idToLevelDict2.0":{"TapDmg":2,"TapDmgFromHelpers":1,"PetDmg":0,"PetGoldQTE":13,"HeavyStrikes":16,"FireTapSkillBoost":0,"PetQTE":0,"Frenzy":0,"BossDmgQTE":0,"AllHelperDmg":15,"ChestGold":1,"HelperDmgSkillBoost":16,"ClanShipDmg":15,"HelperBoost":14,"HelperInspiredWeaken":1,"ClanQTE":16,"HelperDmgQTE":12,"ClanShipStun":0,"MPCapacityBoost":0,"MidasSkillBoost":0,"BurstSkillBoost":0,"CloneDmg":0,"Fairy":0,"ManaStealSkillBoost":0,"CloneSkillBoost":0,"ManaMonster":0,"CritSkillBoost":0,"BossTimer":0,"OfflineGold":11,"MultiMonsters":1,"CritSkillBoostDmg":3,"UltraDagger":1,"StrokeOfLuck":6,"SoulBlade":0,"Cloaking":1,"ForbiddenContract":0,"PoisonedBlade":0,"GuidedBlade":13,"None":0},"firstTimeSeeNewSkillTree":{"$content":true},"hasResetTreeThisPrestige":{"$content":false}}}',
               object_hook = is_content)

print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'SkillTreeModel': {'firstTimeSeeNewSkillTree': True,
                    'hasResetTreeThisPrestige': False,
                    'idToLevelDict2.0': {'AllHelperDmg': 15,
                                         'BossDmgQTE': 0,
                                         'BossTimer': 0,
                                         'BurstSkillBoost': 0,
                                         'ChestGold': 1,
                                         'ClanQTE': 16,
                                         'ClanShipDmg': 15,
                                         'ClanShipStun': 0,
                                         'Cloaking': 1,
                                         'CloneDmg': 0,
                                         'CloneSkillBoost': 0,
                                         'CritSkillBoost': 0,
                                         'CritSkillBoostDmg': 3,
                                         'Fairy': 0,
                                         'FireTapSkillBoost': 0,
                                         'ForbiddenContract': 0,
                                         'Frenzy': 0,
                                         'GuidedBlade': 13,
                                         'HeavyStrikes': 16,
                                         'HelperBoost': 14,
                                         'HelperDmgQTE': 12,
                                         'HelperDmgSkillBoost': 16,
                                         'HelperInspiredWeaken': 1,
                                         'MPCapacityBoost': 0,
                                         'ManaMonster': 0,
                                         'ManaStealSkillBoost': 0,
                                         'MidasSkillBoost': 0,
                                         'MultiMonsters': 1,
                                         'None': 0,
                                         'OfflineGold': 11,
                                         'PetDmg': 0,
                                         'PetGoldQTE': 13,
                                         'PetQTE': 0,
                                         'PoisonedBlade': 0,
                                         'SoulBlade': 0,
                                         'StrokeOfLuck': 6,
                                         'TapDmg': 2,
                                         'TapDmgFromHelpers': 1,
                                         'UltraDagger': 1}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It still is a valid json so you can convert to dictionary and update your key value as you want.

Ex:

```
my_dict=  {
  'SkillTreeModel': {
      # 'idToLevelDict2.0': {...},  # skipping other values
      'firstTimeSeeNewSkillTree': {
        '$content': True
      },
      'hasResetTreeThisPrestige': {
          '$content': False
      }
  }
}
```

Let say if you want to update from `SkillTreeModel.hasResetTreeThisPrestige.content: False` 
to `SkillTreeModel.hasResetTreeThisPrestige: False`

```
import copy

new_dict = copy.deepcopy(my_dict)
for key, value in my_dict['SkillTreeModel'].items():
    if key == 'hasResetTreeThisPrestige':
        new_dict['SkillTreeModel']['hasResetTreeThisPrestige'] = value['$content']

print(new_dict)
```